# How to retreive all the records from elasticsearch in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, elasticsearch, rubygems

There is an upper limit on the number of docs you can get from elastic search(that is 10000). we can use "scroll" to retrieve all the records. Does anyone know how to embed this in code?

There is this method scroll

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/blob/4608fd144277941003de71a0cdc24bd39f17a012/elasticsearch-api/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/scroll.rb

But I don't know how to use it. Could you explain how to use it?

I have tried the "scan". But it is no longer supported in Elasticsearch anymore.

```
# Open the "view" of the index
response = client.search index: 'test', search_type: 'scan', scroll: '5m', size: 10

# Call `scroll` until results are empty
while response = client.scroll(scroll_id: response['_scroll_id'], scroll: '5m') and not 
   response['hits']['hits'].empty? do
      puts response['hits']['hits'].map { |r| r['_source']['title'] }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, but as you mentioned the `scan` parameter for `search_type` is not necessary. I just ran this locally with some test data and it worked:

```rb
# scroll.rb
require 'elasticsearch'

client = Elasticsearch::Client.new

response = client.search(index: 'articles', scroll: '10m')
scroll_id = response['_scroll_id']
while response['hits']['hits'].size.positive?
  response = client.scroll(scroll: '5m', body: { scroll_id: scroll_id })
  puts(response['hits']['hits'].map { |r| r['_source']['title'] })
end
```

Output:

```sh
$ ruby scroll.rb                                                                                         
Title 297                                                                                                
Title 298                                                                                                
Title 299                                                                                                
Title 300
...
```

You can fiddle around with the value for the `scroll` parameter, but something like this should work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

paragraph from elastic official docs :

> We no longer recommend using the scroll API for deep pagination. If
> you need to preserve the index state while paging through more than
> 10,000 hits, use the search_after parameter with a point in time
> (PIT).

[Scroll Official Doc Link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch//reference/current/scroll-api.html)

I recommend to use pagination.

you can use

that limitation in number of hits is for performance inprovements, you can use pagination, Its much faster.

in this way you can use start point with `form` key or use `search_after` key with `sort` and PIT(point in time for prevent from inconsistent result). and you can determinate you hits `size` key with 10 for faster query time.

[Pagination Official Doc Link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html)

for instantiate PIT ID:

```
POST /test/_pit?keep_alive=1m
```

for instantiate pagination:

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "match" : {
      "user.id" : "elkbee"
    }
  },
  "pit": {
    "id":  "46ToAwMDaWR5BXV1aWQyKwZub2RlXzMAAAAAAAAAACoBYwADaWR4BXV1aWQxAgZub2RlXzEAAAAAAAAAAAEBYQADaWR5BXV1aWQyKgZub2RlXzIAAAAAAAAAAAwBYgACBXV1aWQyAAAFdXVpZDEAAQltYXRjaF9hbGw_gAAAAA==", 
    "keep_alive": "1m"
  },
  "sort": [ 
    {"@timestamp": {"order": "asc", "format": "strict_date_optional_time_nanos", "numeric_type" : "date_nanos" }}
  ]
}
```

for get rest of data in pagination:
there is sort key in the result, put it in the `search_after`

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "match" : {
      "user.id" : "elkbee"
    }
  },
  "pit": {
    "id":  "46ToAwMDaWR5BXV1aWQyKwZub2RlXzMAAAAAAAAAACoBYwADaWR4BXV1aWQxAgZub2RlXzEAAAAAAAAAAAEBYQADaWR5BXV1aWQyKgZub2RlXzIAAAAAAAAAAAwBYgACBXV1aWQyAAAFdXVpZDEAAQltYXRjaF9hbGw_gAAAAA==", 
    "keep_alive": "1m"
  },
  "sort": [
    {"@timestamp": {"order": "asc", "format": "strict_date_optional_time_nanos"}}
  ],
  "search_after": [                                
    "2021-05-20T05:30:04.832Z", #you can find this value from sort key in response 
    4294967298
  ],
  "track_total_hits": false                        
}
```